# Elasticsearch filter parent then the nested object

Tags: elasticsearch

Supposing that the indexed data is the following

```
{
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": 20,
    "country": "USA",
    "pets": [
        {
            "name": "Lisa",
            "type": "dog"
        },
        {
            "name": "Max",
            "type": "cat"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Andrea Silva",
    "age": 30,
    "country": "Portugal",
    "pets": [
        {
            "name": "Jack",
            "type": "dog"
        },
        {
            "name": "Ruby",
            "type": "cat"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Matt Leipzin",
    "age": 22,
    "country": "USA",
    "pets": [
        {
            "name": "Travis",
            "type": "dog"
        },
        {
            "name": "Polaris",
            "type": "cat"
        }
    ]
}
```

how should I get the results for the following scenario:

*search for pet owners by name that are from USA and have dogs*.

The `pets` object from result, must contain only dogs and not cats.

I was able to get only owners by name from USA, but don't know how to filter the nested `pets` object.

```
{
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'must': {
                'query_string': {
                    'fields': ['name']
                    'query': <name>
                }
            },
            'filter': {
                'term': {
                    'country': 'USA'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to filter the output (eliminate the dog from the output JSON) or have a result sent by ElasticSearch which contains pet owners who only have dogs and no cats?

Comment: I want to have filtered output, meaning that eliminate cats, and leave only dogs

Comment: @dimmg, do you have solved this problem?